# How to loop n times a list of threads in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

How to loop n (2 to infinite) times a list of long tasks (10 to 10000)?
I'm new to VB.Net and would like to loop thru a list of long tasks while console app is running. 
My code so far is looping thread list only once.

Output: 
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 3
1 - zzz for 939 until: ...
0 - zzz for 1045 until: ...
3 - zzz ...
4 - zzz ...
2 - zzz ...
...
10 - zzz
9 - zzz

```
    Private threadList As List(Of Thread) = New List(Of Thread)
    Private sourceList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Private MaxThreads As Integer = 3
    Private th As Thread
    Private status As Boolean = True
    Private lockers As Object = New Object

Sub Main()
  For x = 1 To 3
    Console.WriteLine("Loop " + x.ToString)
    LoadSource(10)
    For i As Integer = 1 To MaxThreads
        th = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf LongTask))
        th.IsBackground = False
        threadList.Add(th)
        th.Start()
    Next i
  Next
Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

    Private Sub LongTask()
        Dim id As String = String.Empty
        Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        Dim RandomInt As Integer

        While status = True
            If sourceList.Count = 0 Then
                status = False
            Else
                Try
                    SyncLock lockers
                        id = sourceList(0)
                        sourceList.RemoveAt(0)
                    End SyncLock
                    RandomInt = Generator.Next(800, 1600)
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(RandomInt)
                    Console.WriteLine(id + " - zzz for " + RandomInt.ToString + " until: " + Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss.ffff" + " | "))

                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(ex)
                End Try
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadSource(val As Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To val
            sourceList.Add(i)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: what is LoadSource(10) doing and what is the value of MaxThreads, where are you setting that?  Are you sure that MaxThreads is set to the correct value? What's the purpose of threadList?  In LongTask() what is sourceList?

Comment: I've edited my original question. LoadSource() is just loading integers to sourcelist. Every index it's then used as thread name in LongTask(). Basically, this code is to understand how threads and multithreading works.

Comment: So, think the issue is the SyncLock bit.  It looks to me like you're blocking all the threads from executing here, while in the meantime, the main thread has finished executing the initial loops and your threads are now all out of scope

Comment: SynkLock is used to start different threads with different data (product details, stock, unique name in this case). Without SyckLock all threads will "fight" for same data in case maxthreads is lower the sourceList.count. I also consider it important in case of use with Window Form.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code again, I tweaked it to avoid the syslock block, which also took the sourceList.RemoveAt(0) out of the equation.  sourceList is your control variable as in if count gets to 0, nothing happens.  Won't the first thread rremove the id, meaning the next iteration doesn't do anything?

Comment: After removing id 0, id 1 becomes id 0, 2 becomes 1 and so on; id 0 is always the next in For loop so different data is passed to each thread. My guess is that the problem is in the [For x=1 to 3] loop not in longTask() nor second For loop. longTask() can be any time/resource consuming task, while the second For loop just starts a controlled number of concurrent threads. The first For loop is not waiting for all threads to finish before looping again.

Comment: That is what I originally said.  Threads are going out of scope

Comment: Then it should go to loop 2, reload the source list and start threads again, but it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you might be misunderstanding the concept of threading and variable scope.  Maybe I'm missing something.  The main loop will not wait for the threads to finish execution, it will just barrel on through.  Maybe you need to look at handling the thread completion events

Comment: How are you adding integers to a List(Of String)? Referring to sourceList.

Comment: What does "loop thru a list of long tasks" mean?

Comment: Feels like you should be using Task.WhenAll instead!